# Getting empty response body from a http post request to an api

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code. The goal is to get the link with file id.

```
// body parameter 
Map<String, dynamic> body = {'file_id': 123};
String jsonBody = json.encode(body);

// response request
var download_response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://api.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/download'),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Api-Key': 'yCTZwGASncUthpMkMkbQDjcUdrrM2r8v'
    },
    body: jsonBody,
);

// print
debugPrint(download_response.body.toString());
```

I think I should be getting a JSON data response which I'm getting properly with postman but in flutter I'm getting empty response.

Things I tried:

- encoding the body with jsonencode
- correct syntax formatting
- writing the body in plain json string

Answer (score 0):

```dart
var headers = {
  'Api-Key': 'yCTZwGASncUthpMkMkbQDjcUdrrM2r8v',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('https://api.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/download'));
request.fields.addAll({
  'file_id': '123'
});

request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

Comment: same result with this, empty response ! thanks anyway though